# If data structure size is same in user and kernel, isn't the cache miss same as well?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I made a benchmark which has a function reading cache line to measure MPKI (cache miss per kilo instructions) and `syscall` which has also the same function but implemented in a different method(vmalloc). I expected that MPKI will be the same in both level but user MPKI is way too high than kernel MPKI.

I'm currently using `linux-4.14.84` and measuring cache miss and instruction count with `performance monitoring counter`. In syscall, I use `vmalloc` instead of kmalloc due to the limit of slap size.

So, here is the simple code for creating and accessing cache line.

```
void do_test(void *cache)
{
    for (n = 0; n < 100000; n++) {
        for (i = 0; i < CACHE_LINE_NUM; i++) {
            offset = cache + offset;
        }
    }  
}

void init_cache(void *cache, int size, int stride)
{
    int *lastposl;
    cache = mmap(cache, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    madvise(cache, size, MADV_NOHUGEPAGE);

    // in syscall there is no user libary so I use vmalloc
    // cache = vmalloc(size);
    for (offset = 0; offset < size; offset += stride) {
        lastpos = cache + offset;
        *lastpos = offset + stride;
    }
    *lastpos = 0;
}
```

> Accessing cache is not linear. The offset of cache is randomly shuffled.

#### Result

**Accessing cache in user level**

```
L3 Miss User:           4133762
Instruction User:       129473219
L3 Miss Kernel:         4418
Instruction Kernel:     4912652
User MPKI:              31.927545
Kernel MPKI:            0.899311
```

**Accessing cache in kernel level**

```
L3 Miss User:           41512
Instruction User:       13473121
L3 Miss Kernel:         159178
Instruction Kernel:     39499775828
User MPKI:              3.081098
Kernel MPKI:            0.004030
```

I ran them both independently. You can see that even if the code is the same but kernel has the huge instruction count and there is no cache miss in kernel. I expect that syscall should have the same or similar number in Kernel MPKI with the user MPKI in user level looping. Shouldn't it be the same?

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. The compiler optimized every loop so that's why syscall couldn't operate what I meant. I should've put `volatile` in `offset` variable.